# why it remind me of undefined 'pagination' when i did defined it

Tags: python, flask

I met a bug when I write a simple web application use flask.

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
>
> UndefinedError: 'pagintion' is undefined

the code just shown below(/view.py):

```
page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
pagination = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
    page, per_page=current_app.config['FLASKY_POST_PER_PAGE'],
    error_out=False)
posts = pagination.items
return render_template('index.html', form=form, posts=posts,
                       pagination=pagination)
```

why it remind me of undefined 'pagination' when i did defined it.
the traceback shown below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "F:\***\views.py", line 26, in index
    pagination=pagination)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "F:\Github\simp1e\app\templates\index.html", line 3, in top-level template code
    {% import "_macro.html" as macro %}
  File "F:\Github\simp1e\app\templates\base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% block doc -%}
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 4, in block "doc"
    {%- block html %}
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 20, in block "html"
    {% block body -%}
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 23, in block "body"
    {% block content -%}
  File "F:\Github\simp1e\app\templates\base.html", line 48, in block "content"
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
  File "F:\Github\simp1e\app\templates\index.html", line 18, in block "page_content"
    {{ macro.pagination_widget(pagination, '.index') }}
  File "F:\Github\simp1e\app\templates\_macro.html", line 23, in template
    <a href="{% if pagination.has_next %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page = pagintion.page + 1, **kwargs) }}{% else %}#{% endif%}">»</a>
  File "F:\Flask\test\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 397, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
UndefinedError: 'pagintion' is undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="{% if pagination.has_next %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page = pagintion.page + 1, **kwargs) }}{% else %}#{% endif%}">»</a>
```

You wrote pagination wrong here (pagintion).